# animating a custom grid via code behind in wp8.1

Tags: c#, animation, windows-phone-8

i am trying to create a animation using grid. it's a login screen. whenever user taps forget password i want the second grid to animate from top and slide till it stops at center and on tap it's visibility changes. i know how to do it using blend but the thing is i hav a compulsion for doing it from code behind. For that i am using doublekeyframe class. Having real trouble in knowing where is the issue in code behind for animating the second grid. Don't know what the issue and how to animate so serious help needed.

here is my code behind:

```
    Grid gd= this.FindName("SecondaryGrid") as Grid;
    DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames dm=new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
    LinearDoubleKeyFrame l1=new LinearDoubleKeyFrame();
    LinearDoubleKeyFrame l2=new LinearDoubleKeyFrame();



    l1.Value=-703.203;
    l1.KeyTime=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);

    l2.Value=0;
    l2.KeyTime=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

    dm.KeyFrames.Add(l1);
    dm.KeyFrames.Add(l2);

    dm.Duration=new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000));  

    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
    sb.Children.Add(dm);



      Storyboard.SetTarget(dm, gd);
      Storyboard.SetTargetName(dm, gd.Name);
      Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(dm, "Position");

      sb.Begin();
      SecondaryGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: Shouldnt your Secondary Grid Visibility be set to Visible before your animation Begins?

Comment: that doesn't matter .... i have tried that way too   :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Grid gd = this.FindName("SecondaryGrid") as Grid;
        DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames dm = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        LinearDoubleKeyFrame l1 = new LinearDoubleKeyFrame();
        LinearDoubleKeyFrame l2 = new LinearDoubleKeyFrame();



        l1.Value = -703.203;
        l1.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);

        l2.Value = 0;
        l2.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        dm.KeyFrames.Add(l1);
        dm.KeyFrames.Add(l2);

        dm.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000));

        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Children.Add(dm);



        Storyboard.SetTarget(dm, gd);
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(dm, gd.Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(dm, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)");

        sb.Begin();
```

Enjoy :)

**EDIT**

Well what I did was went to XAML and created a SecondaryGrid now in its properties went to render transform and clicked on edit and set Y value as 1 then I saw in XAML that we get

```
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
         <CompositeTransform TranslateX="0" TranslateY="1"/>
  </Grid.RenderTransform>
```

So from this I knew that since there is no position property so I need to set targetProperty as render transform and in that I should Change the Y property since it needs to come from top to bottom which is present inside Composite Transform.TranslateY

Comment: thanks bro ..... that was helpful... i was stuck at it from quite some time. can u just explain a bit . what does the line u wrote means. and do we need to use similar thing for transforming from x-axis ? thanks

Comment: Please check the Edit for details. Cheers.